# how to print new word after two lines using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I need to insert a blank line after two lines in a file that I did with

```
cat rat     hat
pot NOT     lot
big big     big
sit sit     sit
awk '{print};(NR%2==0){print ""}'
cat rat     hat
pot NOT     lot

big big     big
sit sit     sit
```

Actually my main target is to insert a new word after every two lines and I can't solve.

How can I do as I have <= 6000 names in another file in column three and even in this column few have just .(dot) in it.

Second I don't want the blank line after last line.

Answer (score 1):

This seems perfect, to insert fixed WORD every two lines

```
awk '{print}
     (NR%2==0){printf "WORD\n"}'
```

not to insert on last line, i would suggest

```
awk 'NR>2 && (NR%2==1) {printf "WORD\n"}
 { print ; }'
```

number of column in line doesn't matter.

However, just guessing, it is not a fixed word ? a word from the line ? the last one ?

```
awk 'NR>2 && (NR%2==1) {printf "%s\n",last}
 { print ; last=$NF ; }'
```

this will print, the last word every other line.

Replace `$NF` by `$3` to get the third.

Creating a program  is not only code, but being able to describe to others (and oneself) what is to be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk we can print new word when linenumber is even

```
awk '{{print $0}if(NR%2==0)print "word"}'
```

Comment: This adds nothing  to the existing answer.